# MATLAB: Enter to confirm input-dialog?

Tags: matlab, permissions, dialog, user-input

I know there's a way to make the enter-key on the keyboard confirm the inputdlg() dialog, see here:
http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-39UWQT/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-39UWQT

Okay it's a workaround, the problem is, I have to store it in the matlab directory (because as  said on the page: "Since it is dependent on several private functions, newid.m will only work if stored in this location.").. The problem now is, I want to make a code which doesn#t rely on user changes in the Matlab directory because of missing privileges... Is there still another (perhaps dirty) way to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Because I did not know that there is a workaround for this annoying problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. Copy the `newid.m` from http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-39UWQT/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-39UWQT to a arbitrary folder, e.g. into your projects folder
2. Go into the folder where the original `inputdlg()` is stored; you can find this out via `which inputdlg` (e.g. C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\matlab\uitools\inputdlg.m)
3. Go into the `private`-subdirectory and copy the two files `getnicedialoglocation.m` and `setdefaultbutton.m` and paste them into your project's folder where the `newid.m` is located. Now call all your input dialogs by using `newid()` instead of `inputdlg()`

Comment: BTW, I recommend renaming the copied versions of `getnicedialoglocation` and `setdefaultbutton` (file name, function name, and function call inside `newid`) so that they won't stomp and any future updates to the original versions. I just appended `_enter` to the names.